# I can't see the script page for one of the editors

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Owner with add-on for docs, sheets, slides, forms.
And i have 2 editors
I try open script page as owner, script page is opened (https://script.google.com/d/....)
I try open script page as 1 editor, script page is opened
I try open script page as 2 editor, redirect to "https://script.google.com/accounts?continueUrl=..." and message "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time."

I have access to the owner account and the 2 editor account ... When I go to the add-on page, the owner is automatically selected. If I switch to editor, an error occurs (described above)

why i can't open script as 2 editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Apps Script doesn't support Multi Logins

Its a long standing feature request / bug.

> *Unexpected "authorization is required" error from google.script.run after installing Sheets add-on while logged into multiple gmail.com accounts*
>
> [https://issuetracker.google.com/69270374](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374)

If you want to access with two accounts from the same computer, you can use incognito sessions. Otherwise you have to completely log out of all accounts before logging in again with only one.

Go ahead and star that issue to let Google know that it affects you, it will also subscribe your e-mail to updates.